# Dockbar Add application in popup (Liferay6.2 EE)

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

I am trying to implement Add Application (portlet) feature in popup and instead not use Dockbar + Add application feature, So I referred add_application.jsp and created similar jsp which I am calling via aui popup, for now I am just displaying a particular portlet cateogry say Wiki.

But there seems to be some AUI issue while using following script, 
Please guide me through what am I missing here.

```
<aui:script use="liferay-dockbar-add-application,liferay-dockbar-portlet-dd">
    var searchApplication = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />searchApplication');

    var addApplication = new Liferay.Dockbar.AddApplication(
        {
            focusItem: searchApplication,
            inputNode: searchApplication,
            namespace: '<portlet:namespace />',
            nodeList: A.one('#<portlet:namespace />applicationList'),
            nodeSelector: '.drag-content-item',
            selected: !A.one('#<portlet:namespace />addApplicationForm').ancestor().hasClass('hide')
        }
    );

    addApplication.plug(
        Liferay.Dockbar.PortletDragDrop,
        {
            on: {
                dragEnd: function(event) {
                    addApplication.addPortlet(
                        event.portletNode,
                        {
                            item: event.appendNode
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
            srcNode: '#<portlet:namespace />applicationList'
        }
    );
</aui:script>
```

[image]

Comment: there is one liferay wiki link for similar feature but its for older liferay version http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Link+to+Dockbar

Comment: Question is also posted in Liferay forums https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48180244